# fullcalendar renderEvent not working as expected

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have a MySQL table holding some events to be rendered and a couple PHP pages configured to return those events as JSON objects based on the dates passed to it. When you click or drag an event or calendar date, I have a bootstrap modal that pops up, pre-populated with the information stored in the event (if it was an event you clicked or dragged, otherwise it's just a blank form waiting to add a new event) and when I submit the form, it runs an AJAX query to add/update/delete the event in the MySQL table. Once the AJAX returns successfully, I either call 'removeEvent' and pass it the event id (in case of a delete), call a 'renderEvent' and pass it the object that was used to submit the AJAX query (in case of an add), or both (in case of an update).

For whatever reason, the event never renders correctly using this method. The removeEvent works, and grabs the right event, but the add and update don't render the new event with dates/times. I've tried formatting the start and end in a bunch of different ways, but the event is still rendered incorrectly. Basically, the problem with the rendered event is that it renders it on the correct day, and includes the extra data that I've added, which can be verified by clicking the event and opening the modal, but the start time defaults to midnight of that day, and the end time either doesn't exist, or defaults to midnight of the next day. When I reload the page and it gets the data from PHP, the event is rendered with the correct datetime values.

I've tried logging the event object to the console before rendering it, and I can't find anything that looks out of place, i.e. the output of the event in the console looks the same as the output of one of the JSON objects that are coming out of my PHP page.

Can anybody shine any light on this?

- FullCalendar v3.0.1
- Scheduler v1.4.0
- JQuery v3.1.1
- Bootstrap v3.3.7
- bootstrap-datetimejs v4.17.43 (https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker)

The code that is actually rendering the event is in the sendrequest() function, but I'm going to include most of my .js page so you can see what I'm trying to do (I've clipped out a few things to shorten it up, but it's mostly all there)

```
window.onload = initializepage;
//Calendar documentation: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/

function initializepage()
{

    //Build The jQuery Calendar
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives'
        defaultView: 'month',
        editable: true,
        // When you click on an event, it will call the manageevent function and pass the event object to it
        eventClick: function($event) 
        {
            manageevent($event);
        },
        // When you drag an event, it will move it back to where you dragged it
        // after this method executed, the eventClick method above is executed
        eventResize: function($event, $delta, revertfunc) 
        {
            manageevent($event);
            revertfunc();
        },
        eventDrop: function($event, $delta, revertfunc) 
        {
            manageevent($event);
            revertfunc();
        }, 
        eventSources:
        [
            {
                url:    'opscalendar_ajax.php',
            },
            {
                url:    'oncall_ajax.php',
                data:   {
                    groupname: 'Ops'
                }
            }
        ],
        fixedWeekCount: false,
        header: 
        {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'timelineDay,agendaWeek,month,basicYear',
        },
        height: 600,
        resourceGroupField: 'Shifts',
        resourceGroupText: 'Shifts',
        resources: 
        [       
            <!-- deleted for brevity -->
        ],
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        // When you click on a date, or drag across dates, call the addevent function
        select: function($start, $end)
        {
            addevent($start, $end);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        views: {
            <!-- deleted for brevity -->
        },
    });
    // End of JQuery Calendar


    //Some jQuery to make it so that the date picked for end time cannot be before the
    //date picked for the start time

    $(function () {
        $('#starttimepicker').datetimepicker();
        $('#endtimepicker').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
        });
        $("#starttimepicker").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#endtimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });

    });

    // Now we assign some buttons to execute functions instead of submitting a form
    document.getElementById('addEventBtn').onclick = executemanageevent;
    document.getElementById('updateEventBtn').onclick = executemanageevent;
    document.getElementById('deleteEventBtn').onclick = executemanageevent;


    // Some JQuery to clear out and fields that are populated in the modal.
    $("#manageevent").on('hidden.bs.modal', function()
    {
        // Reset form values
        document.getElementById('hiddenid').value = '';
        document.getElementById('shiftdropdown').value = '';
        document.getElementById('starttime').value = '';
        document.getElementById('endtime').value = '';
        document.getElementById('name').value = '';
        document.getElementById('alldayradio2').checked = 'checked';
        document.getElementById('manageeventalert').innerHTML = '';
    });



} // End initializepage function

/* function addevent($start, $end)
 *
 * Populates modal with the dates from user click or drag 
 * Enables the add and cancel buttons
 * Opens the modal so user can see it
 */
function addevent($start, $end)
{
    // Populate dates
    $('#starttimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").date($start);
    $('#endtimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate($start);
    $('#endtimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").date($end);
    document.getElementById('alldayradio2').checked = 'checked';
    // Show Buttons
    $('#addEventBtn').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#cancel').prop("disabled", false);
    // Show Modal
    $('#manageevent').modal({backdrop: 'static'});
    return false;
}

/* function closemodal()
 * 
 * Called after a successful request - just closes the modal
 */
function closemodal()
{
    $('#manageevent').modal('hide')
}


/* function executemanageevent()
 * 
 * When you click any of the buttons (except cancel) this is executed
 * First: it creates an object (like an array, just different) 
 * Second: disable all the buttons so people can't keep clicking
 * Third: take all the values from the modal and put them into the object
 * Fourth: put an alert in the modal header (there's a div for it) and let them know we're trying their request
 * Fifth: send the object to the sendRequest function
 */
function executemanageevent()
{
    // First
    var $datatopass = {};
    $datatopass.mode = this.getAttribute('mode');

    // Second
    $('#addEventBtn').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#updateEventBtn').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#deleteEventBtn').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#cancel').prop("disabled", true);

    // Third
    $titleindex = document.getElementById('name').selectedIndex;
    $datatopass.title = document.getElementById('name').options[$titleindex].text;
    $datatopass.login = document.getElementById('name').value;
    $datatopass.start = document.getElementById('starttime').value;
    $datatopass.end = document.getElementById('endtime').value;
    $datatopass.resourceId = document.getElementById('shiftdropdown').value;
    $datatopass.id = document.getElementById('hiddenid').value;

    var $allday = document.getElementsByName('alldayradio');
    for($i = 0; $i < $allday.length; $i++)
    {
        if($allday[$i].checked == true) 
        {
            $datatopass.allDay = $allday[$i].value;
        }
    }

    // Fourth
    var $infoalert = "<div class='alert alert-info'><strong>Info: </strong>Attempting to submit your request</div>";
    document.getElementById('manageeventalert').innerHTML = $infoalert;

    // Fifth
    $theresults = sendrequest($datatopass);
    console.log($datatopass);
    return false;
}

/* function manageevent($event)
 * 
 * Manage event is called when you click on an event, or drag an event
 * We assume you're going to update, delete, or copy an event and enable all buttons
 * once we've set everything up, show the modal.
 */

function manageevent($event)
{

    // Get data from event
    $title = $event.title;
    $login = $event.login;
    $start = $event.start;
    $end = $event.end;
    $allday = $event.allDay;
    $resourceId = $event.resourceId;
    $id = $event.id;

    // Populate modal fields
    document.getElementById('hiddenid').value = $id;
    document.getElementById('shiftdropdown').value = $resourceId;
    $('#starttimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").date($start);
    $('#endtimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate($start);
    $('#endtimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").date($end);

    document.getElementById('name').value = $login;
    if($allday == true)
    {
        document.getElementById('alldayradio1').checked = 'checked';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('alldayradio2').checked = 'checked';
    }


    // Enable all buttons
    $('#addEventBtn').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#updateEventBtn').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#deleteEventBtn').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#cancel').prop("disabled", false);
    // Show the Modal
    $('#manageevent').modal({backdrop: 'static'});

    return false;
}

/* function sendrequest($thedata)
 * 
 */
function sendrequest($thedata)
{
    var $formdata = "JSON=" + JSON.stringify($thedata);
    var $xhttp;
    $xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    $xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if($xhttp.readyState == 4 && $xhttp.status == 200)
        {
            $theresults = JSON.parse($xhttp.responseText);
            if($theresults.status == 'failure')
            {
                var $warnalert = '<div id="warningAlert" class="alert alert-danger"><strong>' +
                    $theresults.status + '</strong> ' + $theresults.message + '</div>';
                document.getElementById('manageeventalert').innerHTML = $warnalert;
                if($thedata.mode == 'add')
                {
                    $('#addEventBtn').prop("disabled", false);
                    $('#cancel').prop("disabled", false);
                }
                else if($thedata.mode == 'update')
                {
                    $('#addEventBtn').prop("disabled", false);
                    $('#updateEventBtn').prop("disabled", false);
                    $('#cancel').prop("disabled", false);
                }
                else if($thedata.mode == 'delete')
                {
                    $('#deleteEventBtn').prop("disabled", false);
                    $('#cancel').prop("disabled", false);
                }
                var $followup = document.createElement('DIV');
                $followup.setAttribute('class','alert alert-info');
                var $followuptext = document.createTextNode('You may retry your request');
                $followup.appendChild($followuptext);
                document.getElementById('manageeventalert').appendChild($followup);
            }
            else if($theresults.status == 'success')
            {
                var $okayalert = '<div id="warningalert" class="alert alert-success"><strong>' +
                                $theresults.status + '</strong> ' + $theresults.message + '</div>';
                document.getElementById('manageeventalert').innerHTML = $okayalert;

                $thedata.start = moment($thedata.start, 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a');
                $thedata.end = moment($thedata.end, 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a');

                if($thedata.mode == 'add')
                {
                    $thedata.id = $theresults.dbkey;
                    console.log($thedata);
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', $thedata);
                }
                else if($thedata.mode == 'update')
                {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', $thedata.id);
                    console.log($thedata);
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', $thedata);
                }
                else if($thedata.mode == 'delete')
                {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', $thedata.id);
                }
                setTimeout(closemodal, 1500);
            }
        }
    };

    $xhttp.open("POST", "opscalendar_post.php", true);
    $xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    $xhttp.send($formdata);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Updating to Fullcalendar v3.1.0 and Scheduler v1.5.0 doesn't seem to have any impact, but I have done this anyway.